# Как развернуть Flask приложение на сервере с wsgi?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Впервые разворачиваю приложение на Flask на хостинге и не пойму что указывать в wsgi. В шаблоне сказано файл приложения указывать "from hello import application", но у меня приложение имеет другую структуру. На самом верху лежит файл приложения где одна строчка from app import app, потом в структуре проекта идет папка app и в ней **init**.py. Раньше запускал приложение локально через терминал и команду flask run, но как это сделать на хостинге? Пробовал указывать from app import app в файле wsgi, но это так же не дает результата, хотя app.run() и app=Flask(**name**) прописаны. Скриншот структуры проекта прикрепил [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в ISP Manager нужно было всего лишь в файле wsgi указать не `from app import app`, а `from app import app as application`